# Installing Wordpress in its own directory (www.example.com/blog)

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Hi I'm planning to set up a blog for a site and I heard that Wordpress is an easy way to go. However I'd like to install it on its own directory (I don't want all that Wordpress stuff touching or 'sandboxed' in its own place not touching the other stuff outside or my root directory).

Is this possible? I've never used WP before, I'd like some suggestions to any other alternative ways that I can set up a blog (I also use Dreamweaver CS4 if that helps).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, just specify all the correct info during install

Comment: Wow, it's that easy? Thanks Dacto!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probebly need to open a directory, using the server C-panel, and than U can install WP inside this directory.
By the way, most C-panels have WP auto installer.